# Dynamically push files to array in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have problem with angular directive, generally I would like upload files from multiple inputs using in every `input[file]` directive `fileModal`. I would like that every selected file will be push to `objApply` but problem is that only one file is push to array just selected. Could you help me how push multiple files to this array?

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var objApply = [];
        var parsedFile = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var parsedFileSetter = parsedFile.assign;
        element.bind('change', function() {        
            scope.$apply(function() {
                objApply.push(element[0].files[0]);
                parsedFileSetter(scope, objApply);
            });
        });
    }
  };
}])

<input type="file" name="file" file-model="file.upload" 
class="newQuizImgQuestion">
<input type="file" name="file" file-model="file.upload" 
class="newQuizImgQuestion">
```

Comment: `objApply` should be `shared` - move it upper: `var objApply = []; return { restrict: 'A', ... }`